# Is the Likelihood of a Regression Model usually Convex?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, convex-analysis, normal-distribution

This is a question I have always had about Likelihood Functions (e.g. Regression Models):

When dealing with Regression Models in the field of statistics, we are interested in fitting a model to some data (e.g. Covariates and a Response Variable) that describes the "Expected Probability for Observing some Response Conditional on Observing some Specific Set of Covariates": This is the classical regression framework - given some data, we want to create a regression model that allows us to predict the "most likely" value of the response variable given some covariates.

There are different estimation methods that allow us to create this regression model based on the data we have observed. One of these methods is called "Ordinary Least Squares" (OLS) - this method estimates the "Beta Regression Coefficients" that result in the smallest squared distance between the Actual Response and the corresponding Predicted Response by the statistical model. Another method is called "Maximum Likelihood Estimation" (MLE), in which the "Beta Regression Coefficients" are estimated in such a way that the probability of observing the data is maximized, provided that we assume the data actually originated from some (multivariate) probability distribution function (e.g. a Normal Distribution).

For a Simple Linear Regression Model (i.e. with only two Beta Regression Coefficients), for the Maximum Likelihood Formulation, we can write this conditional probability as follows:

[image]

We soon see that the estimation of these Beta Regression Coefficients is effectively an optimization problem - we are interested in finding the values of "b_0, b_1 and s^2" that result in the likelihood formula being maximized (i.e. Arg_Min of the Likelihood):

[image]

Normally, such Optimization Problems would have required us to use some iterative Optimization Algorithm such as Gradient Descent - however, due to the "attractive and convenient" theoretical properties of the Normal Distribution, the above Optimization Problem can give us exact formulas for these Beta Regression Coefficients:

[image]

**My Question:** Do we know if the above Likelihood Equation **L(b_0, b_1, s^2)** that we are trying to Maximize (i.e Optimize) is Convex or Non-Convex?

- I know that in many regression models, the Optimization Problem being solved has exact solutions which do not require iterative Optimization Algorithms - however, I know that some other regression models (e.g. Logistic Regression) do not have exact solutions and do in fact require some iterative Optimization Algorithm (e.g. Newton-Raphson) to estimate the Beta Regression Coefficients.

By doing a quick Google Images Search, it seems that perhaps some of these Likelihood Functions might be Convex and some others might be Non-Convex:

[image]

- **But in general, do we ever study the Convexity of Likelihood Functions in Regression Models? Do we know that if some of these Likelihood Functions are usually Convex (e.g. Linear Regression) and if some of these Likelihood Functions are usually Non-Convex (e.g. Logistic Regression)?**
- **Does the existence of an exact solution to the Beta Regression Coefficients provide some sort of indication regarding the Convexity of the Likelihood Function (e.g. IF exact solution to the Likelihood Function exists THEN Convex ELSE Non-Convex)?**

Thanks!

**Reference:**

- [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf)

Comment: Careful, the log-likelihood for linear regression is concave, not convex (you wish to maximise it, not minimise it). Otherwise, you may look at this:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267404/is-it-the-case-that-the-log-likelihood-always-has-negative-curvature-why

Comment: You seem to be conflating the existence of a closed-form solution with convexity/concavity. The [log likelihood in logistic regression is concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905905/how-to-show-that-log-likelihood-function-in-logistic-regression-is-concave), even though one typically has to find the maximizer with an iterative algorithm since there isn't a closed-form solution.